# USB HID Enumeration with BLED112

Tags: bluetooth, usb, bluetooth-lowenergy, hid, dongle

We are trying to make an USB HID enumeration to simulate a keyboard device on a BLED 112 (with MCU C8051): http://www.silabs.com/products/wireless/bluetooth/bluetooth-low-energy-modules/ble121lr-bluetooth-smart-long-range-module1

We read in the BLUETOOTH SMART MODULE (last version : 12/20/2016) that : "There is no support in the current BLE stack for other types of USB enumeration such as USB HID or other protocols".

But we found examples to make HID keyboard, but only in one way : computer to usb dongle.

So we would like to know if it is possible to make an HID usb enumeration where the dongle send keyboard event to the computer.

If someone have clues, example, or other, it will be great

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just for information, this is the response given by the silicon labs technical team :

"Unfortunately that is not possible, the BLED112 enumerates as a USB CDC device only. It communicates with the PC using BGAPI messages which is our proprietary protocol to interface with our modules."